Proving $\sigma$-compactness of Pontryagin dual
I am reading A First Course in Harmonic Analysis(2nd ed.) by Anton Deitmar. In Theorem 7.1.4, the author proves that the dual group $\hat{A}$ of a LCA group $A$ is also an LCA group. I am stuck with the argument that $\hat{A}$ is $\sigma$-compact.
The main claim is that $(L_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined as below is a compact exhaustion of $\hat{A}$.
$$L_{n} = \left\{  \chi \in \hat{A} \, | \, \chi\left( B_{\frac{1}{n}} \right)\subset \{ z \in \mathbb{T}\,|\,\mathrm{Re}(z)\geq 0 \}  \right\}$$
where $B_{\frac{1}{n}}=B_{\frac{1}{n}}(1)$ is an open ball with radius $1/n$ centered at the identity. To prove that $L_n$ is compact, take a sequence $(\chi_j)$ in $L_n$. There is a countable dense subset $\{a_i\}$ of $A$, and we can show that there is a subsequence $(\chi_{j'})$ such that $(\chi_{j'}(a_i))_{j'}$ converges for all $I$. Now define $\chi(a_i):=\lim \chi_{j'}(a_i)$. Then the author uses the following lemma:

Lemma (7.1.5) Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for every $\chi \in L_{n}$,
$$
 \chi(B_{\delta}) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb{T} \,:\,|z-1|<\epsilon \}$$

Now, if $a_{k}^{-1}a_{l} \in B_\delta$, then $|\chi_{j'}(a_k)-\chi_{j'}(a_{l})|=|\chi_{j'}(a_k^{-1}a_l)-1|<\epsilon$. By taking limit, we get $|\chi(a_k)-\chi(a_l)|\leq\epsilon$. What I don't understand it the following conclusion.

This implies that $\chi$, being the locally uniform limit of the sequence $\chi_{j'}$, extends to a unique continuous map χ : A → T.

In this textbook, there is no notion of Haar measure or invariant metric yet, so the condition $a_k^{-1}a_l \in B_{\delta}$ does not imply that $a_k$ and $a_l$ are 'close enough'. So how can we say that $\chi$ is uniformly continuous?
